# Need help finding $E(X^2)$ for geometric distribution?

Tags: expected-value

Michael plays a random song on
his iPod. He has $2,781$ songs, but only one favorite song. Let X be the number
of songs he has to play on shuffle (songs can be played more than once) in order
to hear his favorite song.

a) find $E(X)$

b) find $E(X^2)$

a is easy, just use $1/p$ where $p = 1/2781$ to find that $E(X)= 2781$

What I struggle with is b)

What is the formula for $E(X^2)$ for a geometric distribution?

Is it simply $E(X^2) = \cfrac{1}{p^2}$?

This doesn't seem right to me, but I can't find anything in my book that would give me $E(X^2)$, can someone show me what the formula is for $E(X^2)$ for a geometric distribution and the derivation if possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A common trick is to use the variance to back out $E(X^2)$ as follows:
$$Var(X)=E(X^2)-(E(X))^2 \iff$$
$$E(X^2)=Var(X)+(E(X))^2$$

For a random variable $X$ that follows a geometric distribution, we have mean $E(X)=\frac{1}{p}$ and $Var(X)=\frac{1-p}{p^2}$ for some success probability p. Hence,
$$E(X^2)=\frac{1-p}{p^2}+(\frac{1}{p})^2=\frac{2-p}{p^2}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$V(X)=E(X^2)-E^2(X)$$

thus

$$E(X^2)=V(X)+E^2(X)$$

---

If you do not know the variance's formula you have to calculate $E(X^2)$ with its definition

$$E(X^2)=\Sigma_x x^2pq^{x-1}=\Sigma_x [x(x-1)+x]pq^{x-1}=\Sigma_x x(x-1)pq^{x-1}+E(X)=\dots=\frac{2q}{p^2}+\frac{1}{p}$$

where $q=1-p$

the proofs of the involved series are not difficult so I leave you this as an exercise

Comment: Why would he know the variance of the geometric distribution if he dosent know the expectation of $X^2$ ?

Comment: @FreeZe: the O.P. stated he know the mean... thus I supposed he knew the variance too  (mean and variance are usually known indicators of a known law). On the countrary it is not difficult to prove $E(X)$ and $E(X^2)$ formulas

Comment: In order to calculate to variance you have to know how to calculate expectation of $ X^2 $, so even if its a well known result, I dont think its legit to use it in order to calculate the expactation of $ X^2$, kind of periodic argument.

Comment: @tommik I am confused in one thing that there is one more version of the geometric distribution that is $q^xp; x=0,1,2,3$ Why can't we use that here? $E(X)=\frac{q}{p}$

Comment: @Daman : my answer supposed $x=1,2,3,...$ because the O.P. stated that $E(X)=1/p$. Reading the given text it is coherent....number of trials before the first success ("number of songs", and not "numbers of failures")

Comment: @tommik That's where my confusion is. How do we know which version is right?

Comment: @Daman : the given text said "number of songs in order to find your favourite one"